# how to get ClassTag[Long] from 10L

Tags: scala, boxing, scala-reflect

Using the following code:

```
val clz = 10L.getClass
val ClassTag(clz)
```

only get the boxed type:

```
java.lang.Long
```

Is there a better solution? Or it is impossible in scala?

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think it is boxed? It most definitely is not:

```
scala> ClassTag(10L.getClass).runtimeClass.getName
res15: String = long

 scala> ClassTag(10L.getClass).runtimeClass == java.lang.Long.TYPE
 res17: Boolean = true

 scala> ClassTag(10L.getClass).runtimeClass == new java.lang.Long(10).getClass
 res18: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Please let me test it in both versions. The behaviour I described is in scala 2.10.6

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a Scala library for this, but using the Java library:

```
val clz = java.lang.Long.TYPE
```